# How an I use html tag to create a calendar event?

Tags: html, calendar

I am organizing an event and I want to create a link, that when clicked, prompts user to create a calendar event. For example...

Tickets go on sale May 1st, 2021 at high noon. [Add the date to your calendar](https://example.com).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow users to create events in Google Calendar.

- Go to Settings > Settings for my calendar > Access permissions and check off Make available to public
- Create the event
- Click More actions > Publish event
- Copy the HTML code displayed.
- Paste this code where you want the event button to display.
- Remove Google Calendar icon if you just want text link.